# Fabricjs 1.6 issue with textbox object alignment

Tags: fabricjs, text-align

There is a bug. If you add a textbox and apply the formatting on selection (not whole `fabric.textbox()`). Now if you try to align the text, it won't align

Here is the fiddle, can anyone help me?
http://jsfiddle.net/fahadnabbasi/kLdng24p/10/

> Double click the textbox, make selection, click on "Apply formatting",
>   now try to align the text and it won't

The similar issue can be replicated on [Kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/) as well.

Comment: did you find solution for this ??

Comment: yes use the latest library and it will work fine